# ThreeJS Tween JS | Move AND Rotate the camera to an object smoothly

Tags: angular, three.js, 3d, tween.js

When I click on an object I can move and rotate around it.

**Here's the non-smooth code :**

```
mouseEvents() {
  window.addEventListener('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Get the mouse position
    this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1
    this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1

    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera)

    var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true)
    for (var i=0; i<intersects.length; i++) {
      // Look at the object and rotate around it
      this.controls.target.set( intersects[i].point.x, intersects[i].point.y, intersects[i].point.z )
      // Move to the object
      this.camera.position.x = intersects[i].point.x
      this.camera.position.y = intersects[i].point.y
      this.camera.position.z = (intersects[i].point.z) + 1000     
    }
  })
}
```

Now I want to do the exact same hing but rotating AND moving smoothly. After a bunch of reading on the internet I found TweenJS and used it. ***The problem is that I can move towards the object smoothly but I don't know how to look at the object and rotate around it smoothly***.

**Here's the smooth code :**

```
mouseEvents() {
  window.addEventListener('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Get the mouse position
    this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1
    this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1

    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera)

    var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true)
    for (var i=0; i<intersects.length; i++) {
      // Look at the object and rotate around it smoothly (using tweenjs I suppose)
      ????????????
      // Move to the object smoothly
      var position = this.camera.position;
      var target = { x : intersects[i].point.x, y: intersects[i].point.y, z: intersects[i].point.z + 1000 };
      var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(position).to(target, 2000);
      tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
      tween.start()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Did I get it correctly, that you create a tween for each object in `intersects` array?

Comment: Yes, each time I click on an object I create a tween basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add a camera.lookAt( yourTargetPoint ) somewhere in your render loop, or in the tweens custom update function.

```
var target = new THREE.Vector3()
mouseEvents() {
  window.addEventListener('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Get the mouse position
    this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1
    this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1

    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera)

    var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true)
    for (var i=0; i<intersects.length; i++) {
      target.copy(intersects[i].point)
      var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(this.camera.position).to(target, 2000)
      tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
      tween.onUpdate(() => {
        this.camera.lookAt( target )
      })
      tween.start()
break; // BREAK HERE BECAUSE WE ONLY CARE ABOUT THE FIRST/AKA NEAREST COLLISION
    }
  })
}
```

You also need to make sure the camera is added to the scene. You can renderer with a camera that ISNT attached to the scene, but then its matrices wont get updated during the rendering phase, in which case you would have to call .updateMatrixWorld() to force update its matrices. But its easier to just scene.add(camera)

Comment: When I do that, I get "Cannot read property 'lookAt' of undefined", do you know why ?

Comment: this.camera.lookAt maybe?

Comment: Ok I no longer have this error and everything is worjking with the onUpdate(), but this is not smooth at all. The camera is smoothly moving towards the object and at the last second rotating and looking at the object

Comment: You have to do the .lookAt AFTER you call controls.update so that it will override the controls.updates lookAt (controls.target) OR remove your call to controls.update.

Comment: I edited my post with the current version of my code, can you edit yours so I can understand what you mean because I must admit I don't get it :s

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. I used 2 different tweens, 1 to move the camera and 1 to make the camera look at the object.

**Here's the code :**

```
mouseEvents() {
  window.addEventListener('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Get the mouse position
    this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1
    this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1

    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera)

    var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true)
    for (var i=0; i<intersects.length; i++) {

      // Move the camera towards the object and stay 1000 above it on z axis
      var positionX = intersects[i].point.x
      var positionY = intersects[i].point.y
      var positionZ = (intersects[i].point.z) + 1000    

      var positionStart = this.camera.position
      var positionEnd = { x : positionX, y: positionY, z: positionZ }
      var tweenPosition = new TWEEN.Tween(positionStart).to(positionEnd, 2000)
      tweenPosition.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
      tweenPosition.start()

      // Make the camera look at the object
      var rotationX = intersects[i].point.x
      var rotationY = intersects[i].point.y
      var rotationZ = intersects[i].point.z

      var rotationStart = this.controls.target
      var rotationEnd = { x : rotationX, y: rotationY, z: rotationZ }
      var tweenRotation = new TWEEN.Tween(rotationStart).to(rotationEnd, 2000)
      tweenRotation.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
      tweenRotation.start()

    }
  })
}
```